# Logar em area restrita de site externo

Tags: php, cakephp

Olá. Tenho um site com formulário de login e quero que, ao o usuário preencher, ele seja redirecionado para a área restrita de outro site, que foi feita usando CakePHP

Comment: poderia explicar a finalidade disso ? você quer um iframe ou quer redirecionar o usuário logando no outro site ?

Comment: Eu tenho um site antigo  feito no wordpress com uma área restrita feita com cakephp. 
Criei um site novo, que tem um form de login e gostaria de redirecionar o usuário para a area restrita do site antigo direto desse form.

Comment: troque o valor do atributo action da tag form, pela url da área restrita do seu blog, use os mesmos nomes dos parâmetros post, se você não conseguiu entender, posta aqui seu formulário e o script da sua área restrita.

Comment: Está questão é ampla demais, poderia ser mais claro sobre como realmente funciona o seu software? Não adianta sair colando um monte de código sem explicar ok? Leia estes links para formular uma boa pergunta e em seguida EDITE a sua pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve :)

Answer (score 0):

Seguir a sugestão do Lucas Soares (definir o action do form como o action do CakePHP) pode não funcionar se estiverem em servidores diferentes caso estes servidores não permitam iteração externa (que é vista como insegura).

Minha sugestão é que use o cookie gerado pelo cake para identificar a sessão e gerá-lo no seu sistema.

Comment: Então. Não consigo achar o action do CakePHP. Na verdade achei meio bizarro usarem cakephp pra área restrita, mas enfim. Estão em servidores diferentes sim. Fiz backup do site antigo com a area restrita do cake e coloquei na pasta do servidor do site novo mas continua não funcionando..